# Users who do not accept answers

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

This question is related to

[Questions without accepted answers and left for months as such flummoxes people.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10528/questions-without-accepted-answers-and-left-for-months-as-such-flummoxes-people)

but touches a different subject. I am asking you about your opinion on users who regularly post questions but never comment on them and never accept any answers for their question. I think that users of this type are actually harmful to the site, much more so than users that are simple hit and run incidents. What is your way of dealing with them?

Personaly, especially with low-rep users, I always check the users answer acceptance history before answering their questions, and I simply ignore users who are obviously not going to put any effort into either commenting on or accepting other answers. Do you have any other tactics against this kind of behaviour?

Comment: A related [MSE thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176369/214632).

Comment: @ArthurFischer Right, that about settles it. Should I just delete my question or should I leave it up for others to find your reference?

Comment: I see no reason why that comment should stop any further discussion on this matter.

Comment: My opinion is that the admins of this site are too focused on increasing the traffic, so they accept any kind of users like the ones you mentioned or those using socket puppets. To those who don't upvote/accept answers I've left them [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) as a comment under their questions, and in few cases I was successful. But there is one (unfortunately I've deleted my comments left under his questions, so I can't find him right now) who have posted almost 50 questions and no accept vote.

Comment: It was impossible for me to convince him to accept any answer!

Comment: You could also use the [comment template](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/4945#4945) explaining accepting answers.

Comment: Here you are: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/120386/user120386. **At present this user has posted 58 questions, and none of them has an accepted answer.**

Comment: @user26857 I don't think naming and shaming is generally appropriate on meta, unless a user is deliberately or egregiously misusing the site - not accepting answers may be annoying, or slightly harmful, but not that serious. As such, I don't think linking to their profile (with a large message in bold) is appropriate here.

Comment: @user61527 Of course, an anonymous user can be disturbed by this! (Btw, he could be a champion of non-acceptance, so people should know him, don't you think?)

Comment: @user26857 As a matter of fact, s/he is not. The current record for "most questions without any accepted answers" is $74$. [Source](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/204110/users-with-most-questions-who-have-not-accepted-any-answers)

Comment: But s/he can be! That database is a little outdated, and our dear user is still active while the champ hasn't seen since February 24.